# Highslide control button

Tags: javascript, css

I wanted to ask for help with Highslide Gallery. First I had problems with control bar, but I finished it and now I was left with last problem. In my control bar when you move mouse on "Pause" it's inactive and works as "Next" and starting from it every button is like "Next" works as "Move" in other words it's like hyperlinks moved one position to the left.
It would work if only every button starting with "Next" moved 30px to the right, but no matter what I try it doesn't work.

```
    /* Ajax */
.highslide-container div {
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica;
    font-size: 10pt;
    top:85%;
    }
.highslide {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.highslide img {
    border: 2px solid silver;
}
.highslide:hover img {
    border-color: gray;
}

.highslide-active-anchor img, .highslide-active-anchor:hover img {
    border-color: black;
}
.highslide-image {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    background: gray;
}
.highslide-wrapper, .rounded-white {
    background: white;
}
.highslide-image-blur {
}
.highslide-caption {
    display: none;
    border-top: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 5px;
    background: white;
}
.highslide-heading {
    display: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}
.highslide-dimming {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
}
.highslide-loading {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    padding-left: 22px;
    background-image: url(../javascript/images/loader.white.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 3px 1px;
}
a.highslide-credits,
a.highslide-credits i {
    padding: 2px;
    color: silver;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
}
a.highslide-credits:hover,
a.highslide-credits:hover i {
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;
}

/*background: url(javascript/images/controlbar-white.gif)*/
/* Controls. See http://www.google.com/search?q=css+sprites */

.highslide-controls {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 210px;
    height: 36px;
    background: url(javascript/images/controlbar-white.gif) 0px -90px no-repeat;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.highslide-controls ul {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 210px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(javascript/images/controlbar-white.gif) 0px -30px no-repeat;

}
.highslide-controls li {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 0;
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;
}
.highslide-controls a {
    background-image: url(javascript/images/controlbar-white.gif) 0px -90px no-repeat;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    outline: none;
}
.highslide-controls a.disabled {
    cursor: default;
}
.highslide-controls a.disabled span {
    cursor: default;
}
.highslide-controls a span {
    /* hide the text for these graphic buttons */
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


/* The CSS sprites for the controlbar */
.highslide-controls .highslide-previous a {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.highslide-controls .highslide-previous a:hover {
    background-position: 0px -30px;
}
.highslide-controls .highslide-previous a.disabled {
    background-position: 0 -60px !important;
}
.highslide-controls .highslide-play a {
    background-position: -30px 0;
}
.highslide-controls .highslide-play a:hover {
    background-position: -30px -30px;
}
.highslide-controls .highslide-play a.disabled {
    background-position: -30px -60px !important;
}
.highslide-controls .highslide-pause a {
    background-position: -60px 0;
}
.highslide-controls .highslide-pause a:hover {
    background-position: -60px -30px;
}

.highslide-controls .highslide-pause a.disabled{
    background-position: -60px -60px !important;
}

.highslide-controls .highslide-next a {
    background-position: -90px 0;
}
.highslide-controls .highslide-next a:hover {
    background-position: -90px -30px;
}
.highslide-controls .highslide-next a.disabled {
    background-position: -90px -60px !important;
}
.highslide-controls .highslide-move a {
    background-position: -120px 0;
}
.highslide-controls .highslide-move a:hover {
    background-position: -120px -30px;
}
.highslide-controls .highslide-full-expand a {
    background-position: -150px 0;
}
.highslide-controls .highslide-full-expand a:hover {
    background-position: -150px -30px;
}
.highslide-controls .highslide-full-expand a.disabled {
    background-position: -150px -30px !important;
}
.highslide-controls .highslide-close a {
    background-position: -180px 0;
}
.highslide-controls .highslide-close a:hover {
    background-position: -180px -30px;
}
```

I didn't change anything in Java Script file, only worked with this part of CSS file.
Firefox for line with "Pause" button:

```
<li style="display: none;" class="highslide-pause"><a href="#" title="Zatrzymaj slajd (spacja)"><span>Zatrzymaj</span></a></li>
```

When working buttons:

```
<li class="highslide-next"><a href="#" title="Następne"><span>Następne</span></a></li>
```

Sorry for problem and thanks for any help with it.

---

Sorry, mistake was on my side. I should only change line:

```
 this.btn.pause.style.display = 'none';
```

and it started displaying "Pause" like it should but only for first open photo :/

After changing all 'none' to ' ' for "Pause" in java script it works.